# ios diagnostics usage cannot select send

Tags: ios, send, privacy, diagnostics

In my iPad, current version iOS8.0.2, in privacy - Diagnostics & Usage, cannot select "Automatically Send", only checked "Don't Send".
May I know is there any reason to disable such option pls?
Thx a lot